# IDEA play 2 framework

Tags: intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I would like to ask if there is any solution for Play2 framework with IDEA.

I've made play-java project with typesafe activator , than imported to idea as SBT project , but IDEA gives me an error : `cannot resolve method 'ok(java.lang.Object)'`.

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ do you have? Ultimate or community?

Comment: ultimate 14.1.4 , I've tried to compile the app before import into IDEA and It looks it works